# how to properly call jquery function from php?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, call

UPDATE:

I'm making a like/dislike voting program and it has worked the way I want it in Firefox 3, Chrome, and Safari. However, it doesn't seem to be working in Firefox 4. For example, I've made a form such that after the user clicks the submit button and the data is sent into the SQL table, a jquery animation is supposed to play. This is the full code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="opacity.js"></script>



<link href="voter.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<?php


mysql_connect("","","") or die("Error connecting to db");
mysql_select_db("") or die("Error connecting to db");

$currAdd2 = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
$currAdd2 = substr($currAdd2, 0, -9);
$currAdd2 = substr($currAdd2, 11);

$numrow1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM rate WHERE apt = '$currAdd2' AND likes = 1 ");
$numlikes = mysql_num_rows($numrow1); 

$numrow2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM rate WHERE apt = '$currAdd2' AND likes = 0 ");
$numdislikes = mysql_num_rows($numrow2);

$numrow3 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM rate WHERE apt = '$currAdd2'  ");
$totalvotes = mysql_num_rows($numrow3);

$likewidth = ($numlikes/($totalvotes+1)) * 400;
$dislikewidth = ($numdislikes/($totalvotes+1)) * 400;
?>
<form action= '<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>'; method='post'>
<table align='left' width='500px' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>
<? echo"      
      <tr>
        <td>
            <div id='blue'><input type='image' name='blue' id='likebutton' value='blue' src='../zrating/like.png' 

            /></div>

        </td>
        <td>
        <b>$numlikes Like</b>
        <div id='like' style='width:$likewidth'><div id='dis'></div></div><br>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
            <div id='red'><input type='image' name='red' id='dislikebutton' value='red' src='../zrating/dislike.png'  

            /></div>

        </td>
        <td>
            <b>$numdislikes Dislike</b>
            <div id='dislike' style='width:$dislikewidth'><div id='dis'></div></div><br>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <td>
      </td>
      <td>
      <div id='success'><br><br>Thanks for voting!</div>
      <div id='fail'><br><br>You are only allowed 1 vote per apartment.</div>     
      </td>
      </tr>
  </table>
</form>
";


//check ip address
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))   //check ip from share internet
    {
      $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    }
    elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))   //to check ip is pass from proxy
    {
      $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    }
    else
    {
      $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }



if ( isset( $_POST['blue'] ) )
{

    $currAdd = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    $currAdd = substr($currAdd, 0, -9);
    $currAdd = substr($currAdd, 11);

    $ipquery = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM rate WHERE ip = '$ip' AND apt = '$currAdd' ");
    $ipquery = mysql_fetch_assoc($ipquery);
    $ipquery = $ipquery['ip'];


    if ($ipquery == $ip)
    {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery.js'></script>";


                echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
                 $(document).ready(function()
    {
    $('#fail').animate({width:300},1000);
    $('#fail').animate({height:100},1000);
    $('#fail').animate({width:300,height:100},1400);
    $('#fail').fadeOut(5000);

    }); </script>";

    }
    else
    {

    mysql_query ("INSERT INTO rate VALUES ('','$currAdd', '1', '$ip')");            

    $rankqry = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM rank WHERE apt = '$currAdd' ");
    $rankqry = mysql_fetch_assoc($rankqry);
    $rankqry = $rankqry['rank'];

    $rankupdate = $rankqry + 1;

        if($rankupdate < 0)
        {
        $rankupdate = 0;
        }

    mysql_query ("UPDATE rank SET rank = '$rankupdate' WHERE apt = '$currAdd' ");
    $likesqry = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM rank WHERE apt = '$currAdd' ");
    $likesqry = mysql_fetch_assoc($likesqry);
    $likesqry = $likesqry['likes'];

    $likesupdate = $likesqry +1;

    mysql_query ("UPDATE rank SET likes = '$likesupdate' WHERE apt = '$currAdd' ");

            echo "<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery.js'></script>";


        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
                 $(document).ready(function()
    {
    $('#success').animate({width:300},1000);
    $('#success').animate({height:100},1000);
    $('#success').animate({width:300,height:100},1400);
    $('#success').fadeOut(5000);

    }); </script>";

}

}


if ( isset( $_POST['red'] ) )
{
    $currAdd = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    $currAdd = substr($currAdd, 0, -9);
    $currAdd = substr($currAdd, 11);

    $ipquery = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM rate WHERE ip = '$ip' AND apt = '$currAdd' ");
    $ipquery = mysql_fetch_assoc($ipquery);
    $ipquery = $ipquery['ip'];

    if ($ipquery == $ip)
    {
                echo "<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery.js'></script>";


                echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
                 $(document).ready(function()
    {
    $('#fail').animate({width:300},1000);
    $('#fail').animate({height:100},1000);
    $('#fail').animate({width:300,height:100},1400);
    $('#fail').fadeOut(5000);

    }); </script>";


    }
    else
    {

mysql_query ("INSERT INTO rate VALUES ('','$currAdd', '0', '$ip')");    

$rankqry = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM rank WHERE apt = '$currAdd' ");
$rankqry = mysql_fetch_assoc($rankqry);
$rankqry = $rankqry['rank'];

$rankupdate = $rankqry - 1;

if($rankupdate < 0)
{
    $rankupdate = 0;
}


mysql_query ("UPDATE rank SET rank = '$rankupdate' WHERE apt = '$currAdd' ");

$dislikesqry = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM rank WHERE apt = '$currAdd' ");
$dislikesqry = mysql_fetch_assoc($dislikesqry);
$dislikesqry = $dislikesqry['dislikes'];

$dislikesupdate = $dislikesqry +1;

    mysql_query ("UPDATE rank SET dislikes = '$dislikesupdate' WHERE apt = '$currAdd' ");

            echo "<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery.js'></script>";



                    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
                 $(document).ready(function()
    {
    $('#success').animate({width:300},1000);
    $('#success').animate({height:100},1000);
    $('#success').animate({width:300,height:100},1400);
    $('#success').fadeOut(5000);

    }); </script>";


    }
}
?>
```

I used version 1.4.2 of the jquery library and the latest version but still no luck. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: is it an ajax-request or a regular page request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using the latest version of jQuery (1.6.1), and the following code just ran on my server perfectly fine:

```
<?php

echo '<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<div id="success">
    Success! Success! Success! Success! Success! Success! Success! Success! Success! Success! Success! Success! Success! Success!
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(\'#success\').animate({width:300},1000);
    $(\'#success\').animate({height:100},1000);
    $(\'#success\').animate({width:300,height:100},1400);
    $(\'#success\').fadeOut(5000);
});
</script>
</body></html>';

?>
```

EDIT: Here's a [link to my test PHP script](http://iyikes.com/jqueryphptest.php)

2nd EDIT: I wanted to add something to my answer. Without context, it is hard to tell if this is an issue, but make sure you are loading the jQuery JS file before you make any calls to the jQuery. The animation calls you made can be done outside of the HTML chunk, but it cannot be done before you load the jQuery JS file. For example, this would work:

```
<?php

echo '<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<div id="success">
    Success! Success! Success! Success! Success! Success! Success! Success! Success! Success! Success! Success! Success! Success!
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
</body></html>';

if ( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) )
{
    mysql_query ("INSERT INTO table VALUES ('','', '', '')");

    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
             $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('#success').animate({width:300},1000);
        $('#success').animate({height:100},1000);
        $('#success').animate({width:300,height:100},1400);
        $('#success').fadeOut(5000);
    }); </script>";
}

?>
```

But this will not:

```
<?php

echo '<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<div id="success">
    Success! Success! Success! Success! Success! Success! Success! Success! Success! Success! Success! Success! Success! Success!
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(\'#success\').animate({width:300},1000);
    $(\'#success\').animate({height:100},1000);
    $(\'#success\').animate({width:300,height:100},1400);
    $(\'#success\').fadeOut(5000);
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
</body></html>';

?>
```

Using online jQuery 1.6.1 file

```
<form action= '<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>'; method='post'>
<table align='left' width='500px' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>
<?
   // Using online jQuery 1.6.1 file
   echo"      
      <tr>
        <td>
            <div id='blue'><input type='image' name='blue' id='likebutton' value='blue' src='../zrating/like.png' 

            /></div>

        </td>
        <td>
        <b>$numlikes Like</b>
        <div id='like' style='width:$likewidth'><div id='dis'></div></div><br>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
            <div id='red'><input type='image' name='red' id='dislikebutton' value='red' src='../zrating/dislike.png'  

            /></div>

        </td>
        <td>
            <b>$numdislikes Dislike</b>
            <div id='dislike' style='width:$dislikewidth'><div id='dis'></div></div><br>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <td>
      </td>
      <td>
      <div id='success'><br><br>Thanks for voting!</div>
      <div id='fail'><br><br>You are only allowed 1 vote per apartment.</div>     
      </td>
      </tr>
  </table>
</form>
";

echo "<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.1.min.js'></script>";


                echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
                 $(document).ready(function()
    {
    $('#fail').animate({width:200},1000);
    $('#fail').animate({height:100},1000);
    $('#fail').fadeOut(5000);

    }); </script>";
?>
```

Comment: I've put in <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script> in the PHP tags but it still doesn't work. I'm gonna post the full code in my OP.

Comment: It works alright on my server. Are you sure you're including the right script? When I look at your full code in your OP, it shows `jquery.js`. Is that the right path to your jQuery file? All I did was copy your form and the first if statement's animation as well as change the if statement to point to the jQuery1.6.1 JS file on my server here:
http://iyikes.com/phpservertest.php

Comment: Did you run it in Firefox 4? I changed the source of the js file to http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js but its still not working. On other forums where I've posted, they've mentioned that my script is invalid because I didn't include the doctype, html tag, head tag, and body tag and that I'm running in "quirks" mode. I then included the doctype and the tags but problem not resolved.

Comment: Yup, I ran it in FF4 and it's working fine. It must be something you're doing with your code. Try using the EXACT code that I've edited in that's commented "Using online jQuery 1.6.1 file"

Comment: The code in "Using online jQuery 1.6.1 file" looks like part of the code was cut off in the beginning? I copy pasted the code in the frame starting with "/></div>" and the animation played in Firefox 4. What does this mean in relation to my problem?

Comment: Sorry about that, I edited the post (forgot to add a new line before the code). Anyways, it probably (not definitely) means that your if statements are being incorrectly tested or are just incorrect. Try changing some of your if statements to obviously true values like `if (true)` and see if the animation fires. If so, you know that there is an issue between the two values you are comparing.

Comment: putting in if (true) worked. Another thing I've noticed is that after removing much of the php code after the form script, it still wouldn't work but replacing if ( isset ($_POST['blue']) ) with if (true) works. Why does if(isset ($_POST['blue'])) work with Chrome, Safari, and Firefox 3 then?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure. I would try `print_r($_POST)` to see if the values are actually set. I would also try using something like `if ($_POST['blue'] != '')` (or null, I forget which one it would be).

Comment: After I put in print_r($_POST) and not clicked any of the buttons, I got Array() but if I click the blue button, I get Array ( [blue_x] => 59 [blue_y] => 35 ). If I await a few seconds and then click the blue button again, the blue_x and blue_y values change.

Comment: Okay, so you should be checking `$_POST['blue_x']` or `$_POST['blue_y']` or both. It seems that `$_POST['blue']` doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

If it is working on all browsers except for Firefox 4 you may want to look at this thread:

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-1-4-x-firefox-4-beta-ajax-callbacks

Is the data submitted with ajax?

Comment: Nope, don't think I ever used ajax before.

Comment: You can assume though that if it works arross all browers except FF4 it is not down to your script. Doesn't fixe your problem though.

Comment: I hope so! Firefox has been, in my point of view, the ideal browser. Since FF4 not so sure. I think the next update is FF5 though.